# Madrid Barajas to Toledo transfer

Tags: airport-transfer, spain, madrid

What are some transfer options from Madrid Barajas to Toledo. 
My family of 5 people (4 adults + 1 kid) arrives late, thus cannot use the public transportation.
I did not find any companies that do non-luxury transfer.
Do these exist?

Comment: Did you try emailing / ringing some local taxi companies?

Comment: Toledo local taxi do not have cars that have > 5 seats. I will check with Spanish taxis also.

Comment: At what time do you arrive to Madrid? There are trains to Madrid from 6:50 to 21:50 most days, and night shift transport from airport to the city (and the train station). If you are ok to stay a few hours in some place may be it's an option.

Answer (score 1):

According to [Wikitravel](http://wikitravel.org/en/Madrid#By_plane), there are at least a couple of options:

- [MadShuttle](http://www.madshuttle.com/en/) - from 8.66 Euros per person, and they cater to all sorts of group sizes.
- [EuropeShuttle](http://www.europeshuttle.com/) - from 26 Euros per *vehicle*, this is arguably cheaper for your large group, if they have a van available to take all of you.
- There's also the [24 hour shared airport shuttle](http://www.airportshuttlemadrid.com/) - from 8.50 Euros per passenger.

Naturally with the first two, you'll want to contact them in advance and confirm that an appropriate vehicle is available.

Comment: thanks, but all of them starts from 200 for a group of 5. Still more or less ok...but expensive.

Comment: @chupvl really? That's frustrating given their advertised prices.  Could you not split your group for the trip? Would make it a lot easier.

Comment: Nope, the taxi cost 100 euros.